# Catching an Exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, database, error-handling

I have a simple button ADD

And ADD_Click code is:

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        myConnection.Open();


        string hesap = Label1.Text;
        string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
        cmd.Connection = myConnection;



        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
        myConnection.Close();
    }
```

What i want is, if anybody adding a data with same `HESAP` (primary key) i want a alert() function with this words. "Already there is a same data" or any words. Doesn't matter.

How can i do that?

**NOTE**: I want just the same HESAP value getting and catching an error.

Comment: unrelated; add some `using` here; if this errors frequently you could starve the connection-pool until GC kicks in

Comment: Wow you are doing all this business operation in a UI button click event handler, you are not catching any exception and you do an ExecuteReader instead of an ExecuteNonQuery... I think you should read much about ADO.NET and ASP.NET, seriously !

Comment: @Davide you are right. I'm a beginner. But how can i use catching exception in this code? Just i want if there is an error, start the javascript alert function with some error words..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string hesap = Label1.Text;
    string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
            cmd.Connection = myConnection;

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Number == 2627)
                {
                    // Add a javascript alert to let the user know that the same HESAP value already exists.
                }
                else
                {
                    // Rethrow the exception.
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could either add another query first that checks if the key exists using a simple select-statement, or you could (uglier solution imo) try/catch the SqlException that ExecuteReader will throw if there is a primary key-violation.

Answer (score 2):

I am making an assumption that the database would have multiple simultaneous users.

I would recommend doing a try/catch on the SQLException for the primary-key violation as Andreas mentioned. I would advise this over making two queries because application flow (from separate users) could be as follows:

- User A checks if key "A" is used.
- User B checks if key "A" is used. (Both of them at this point say no)
- User A inserts key "A".
- User B inserts key "B". This will fail and cause a SQLException for primary-key violation.

Comment: You're right, but it's possible to add a transaction in the C#-code to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several improvements that can and should be made to the original code posted as noted by other users (using statements, ExecuteNonQuery, etc) if all you want to do is detect primary key constraint violations then you can check the error number of the SqlException in a catch block.  The error number would be 2627.  Using your existing code, it would look like this...

```
try
{
    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServerCstr"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
    myConnection.Open();


    string hesap = Label1.Text;
    string musteriadi = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    string avukat = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO AVUKAT VALUES (@MUSTERI, @AVUKAT, @HESAP)", myConnection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HESAP", hesap);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MUSTERI", musteriadi);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AVUKAT", avukat);
    cmd.Connection = myConnection;



    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    myConnection.Close();
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        // Add a javascript alert to let the user know that the same HESAP value already exists.
    }
    else
    {
        // Rethrow the exception.
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
//open connection
//Insert
}
catch(SQLException Excep)
{
//If primary key violation alert()
}
finally
{
//Close connection
}
```

this might help u