# Spreading of business logic between DB and client

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, design-patterns

Ok guys, another my question is seems to be very widely asked and generic. For instance, I have some accounts table in my db, let say it would be accounts table. On client (desktop winforms app) I have appropriate functionality to add new account. Let say in UI it's a couple of textboxes and one button.

Another one requirement is account uniqueness. So I can't add two same accounts. My question is should I check this account existence on client (making some query and looking at result) or make a stored procedure for adding new account and check account existence there. As it for me, it's better to make just a stored proc, there I can make any needed checks and after all checks add new account. But there is pros and cons of that way. For example, it will be very difficult to manage languagw of messages that stored proc should produce.

---

**POST EDIT**

I already have any database constraints, etc. The issue is how to process situation there user is being add an existence account.

---

**POST EDIT 2**

The account uniqueness is exposed as just a simple tiny example of business logic. My question is more abour handling complicated business logic on that accounts domain.

So, how can I manage this misunderstanding?

I belive that my question is basic and has proven solution. My tools are C#, .NET Framework 2.0. Thanks in advance, guys!

Comment: Use Database constraints to to ensure Uniqueness of the accounts.. neither client or stored proc..

Comment: It is understood from the beginning what I use database constraints. The issue is how process situation there user being add existence account.

Comment: Well, you can always catch `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`. if you want to make sure before the user submits the data (as when creating new email if the user name is used it notifies you right away) then you have to make a small function or stored proc to check that as soon as the user leaves the text box.

Comment: check this post, the answer shows how to catch primary key exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078772/catching-an-exception-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

If the application is to be multi-user ( i.e. not just a single desktop app with a single user, but a centralised DB with the app acting as clients maybe on many workstations), then it is not safe to rely on the client (app) to check for such as uniqueness, existance, free numbers etc as there is a distinct possibility of change happening between calls (unless read locking is used, but this often become more of an issue than a help!).

There is the ability of course to precheck and then recheck (pre at app level, re at DB), but of course this would give extra DB traffic, so depends on whether it is a problem for you.

When I write SPROCs that will return to an app, I always use the same framework - I include parameters for a return code and message and always populate them. Then I can use standard routines to call them and even add in the parameters automatically. I can then either display the message directly on failure, or use the return code to localize it as required (or automate a response). I know some DBs (like SQL Svr) will return Return_Code parameters, but I impliment my own so I can leave inbuilt ones for serious system based errors and unexpected failures. Also allows me to have my own numbering systems for return codes (i.e. grouping them to match Enums in the code and/or grouping by severity)

On web apps I have also used a different concept at times. For example, sometimes a request is made for a new account but multiple pages are required (profile for example). Here I often use a header table that generates a hidden user ID against the requested unique username, a timestamp and someway of recognising them (IP Address etc). If after x hours it is not used, the header table deletes the row freeing up the number (depending on DB the number may never become useable again - this doesn;t really matter as it is just used to keep the user data unique until application is submitted) and the username. If completed correctly, then the records are simply copied across to the proper active tables.

//Edit - To Add:

> Good point. But account uniqueness is just a very tiny simple sample.
>   What about more complex requirements for accounts in business logic?
>   For example, if I implement in just in client code (in winforms app) I
>   will go ok, but if I want another (say console version of my app or a
>   website) kind of my app work with this accounts I should do all this
>   logic again in new app! So, I'm looking some method to hold data right
>   from two sides (server db site and client side). – kseen yesterday

If the requirement is ever for mutiuse, then it is best to separate it. Putting it into a separate Class Library Project allows the DLL to be used by your WinForm, Console program, Service, etc. Although I would still prefer rock-face validation (DB level) as it is closest point in time to any action and least likely to be gazzumped.

The usual way is to separate into three projects. A display layer [DL] (your winform project/console/Service/etc) and Business Application Layer [BAL] (which holds all the business rules and calls to the DAL - it knows nothing about the diplay medium nor about the database thechnology) and finally the Data Access Layer [DAL] (this has all the database calls - this can be very basic with a method for insert/update/select/delete at SQL and SPROC level and maybe some classes for passing data back and forth). The DL references only the BAL which references the DAL. The DAL can be swapped for each technology (say change from SQL Server to MySQL) without affecting the rest of the application and business rules can be changed and set in the BAL with no affect to the DAL (DL may be affected if new methods are added or display requirement change due to data change etc). This framework can then be used again and again across all your apps and is easy to make quite drastic changes to (like DB topology).

Answer (score 0):

This type of logic is usually kept in code for easier maintenance (which includes testing).  However, if this is just a personal throwaway application, do what is most simple for you.  If it's something that is going to grow, it's better to put things practices in place now, to ease maintenance/change later.

I'd have a AccountsRepository class (for example) with a AddAcount method that did the insert/called the stored procedure.  Using database constraints (as HaLaBi mentioned), it would fail on trying to insert a duplicate.  You would then determine how to handle this issue (passing a message back to the ui that it couldn't add) in the code.  This would allow you to put tests around all of this.  The only change you made in the db is to add the constraint.

Just my 2 cents on a Thrusday morning (before my cup of green tea). :)

Comment: Good point. But account uniqueness is just a very tiny simple sample. What about more complex requirements for accounts in business logic? For example, if I implement in just in client code (in winforms app) I will go ok, but if I want another (say console version of my app or a website) kind of my app work with this accounts I should do all this logic again in new app! So, I'm looking some method to hold data right from two sides (server db site and client side).

Comment: you should separate your UI from your DAO (Data access object) from your DB.. 3 tiers. this way you can have many different Clients (Console, Webpage, Winform, WPF...etc.) without having to rewrite any thing related to Data Access..

Comment: Should I organize this 3 tiers as different projects in solution or what?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You an have folders/namespaces to separate the layers.  If the size of classes is large, or it becomes unwieldy, separate into individual projects.

Comment: As @BlessYahu said, you can use one project. but in your case because you want to have multiple client types it is better to separate them and then simply add a reference to the project in your clients.. simple and easy.

Answer (score 0):

i think the answer - like many - is 'it depends'

for sure it is a good thing to push logic as deeply as possible towards the database. This prevent bad data no matter how the user tries to get it in there.

this, in simple terms, results in applications that TRY - FAIL - RECOVER when attempting an invalid transaction.  you need to check each call(stored proc, or triggered insert etc) and IF something bad happens, recover from that condition. Usually something like tell the user an issue occurred, reset the form or something, and let them try again.

i think at a minimum, this needs to happen.

but, in addition, to make a really nice experience for the user, the app should also preemptively check on certain data conditions ahead of time, and simply prevent the user from making bad inserts in the first place.

this is of course harder, and sometimes means double coding of business rules (one in the app, and one in the DB constraints) but it can make for a dramatically better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is more of being methodical than technical:

- Implement - "Defensive Programming" & "Design by Contract"
- If the chances of a business-rule being changed over time is very less, then apply the constraint at database-level
- Create a "validation or rules & aggregation layer (or class)" that will manage such conditions/constraints for entity and/or specific property
- A much smarter way to do this would be to make a user-control for the entity and/or specific property (in your case the "Account-Code"), which would internally use the "validation or rules & aggregation layer (or class)"
- This will allow you to ensure a "systematic-way-of-development" or a more "scalable  & maintainable" application-architecture
- If your application is a website then along with placing the validation on the client-side it is always better to have validation even in the business-layer or C# code as well
- When ever a validation would fail you could implement & use a "custom-error-message" library, to ensure message-content is standard across the application
- If the errors are raised from database itself (i.e., from stored-procedures), you could use the same "custom-error-message" class for converting the SQL Exception to the fixed or standardized message format

I know that this is all a bit too much, but is will always good for future.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you should not depend on a specific Storage Provider (DB [mysql, mssql, ...], flat file, xml, binary, cloud, ...) in a professional project all constraint should be checked in the business logic (model).

The model shouldn't have to know anything about the storage provider.

Uncle Bob said something about architecture and databases: http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2011/11/22/Clean-Architecture.html